# How to push part of a line outside the margin?

Tags: indentation, margins

I want one particular line to exceed the margin like this...

```
    My text
    My text
 My special Text.
    My text.
 My special text.
```

How can I achieve this?

I have tried to use

```
\reversemarginpar
\marginpar{My} special text
```

But it adds the 'My' on the left edge of the page. Thanks.

Comment: Are each of the lines a paragraph in your example? Or do they form part of the same (single) paragraph?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a start-of-a-paragraph "undent", this is easily achieved using a `\makebox[0pt][r]{..}` alignment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
My text. \par
My text. \par
\makebox[0pt][r]{My }special Text. \par
My text. \par
\noindent\llap{My }special text.
\end{document}
```

This sets the text in a box of width `0pt` (avoiding overfull `\hbox`es) and `r`ight-aligned, pushing it into the left margin. You could also use `\llap`, which does the same, but you need to "start" the paragraph first before this takes effect.

It would also be possible to allow this "undent" mid-paragraph.

Comment: It worked as I expected. Thank you. May ask, what does setlength do? I tried without it, that also worked.. My text is like this <\textbf{\emph{\makebox[0pt][r]{MY}1: example text>

Comment: A paragraph is typically indented with `\parindent` (default is `15pt`). Using `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` kills this indent so all paragraphs start flush with the left margin. I used this merely to illustrate the "undentation". In you code, I would probably use `\makebox[0pt][r]{\textbf{\emph{My }}}`. In other words, set the box last (on the outside).